# Instantiating Objects Dynamically (Mistic Query Builder)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm new to JavaScript, focusing primarily on Java/PHP development. The JS applications I've built in the past have been pretty hackish, untestable, and unextensible.

I'm now trying to create an application that interfaces with data in a more appropriate manner. Basically I'm building a user interface for creating rules/actions that our support team and end users can access. The logic for the application contains a lot of Boolean and logical operators and just requires that some arbitrary set of conditions be met, and then will apply certain actions.

So, I've pretty much settled on a query builder type of application, and I love [Mistic's work](https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder). Unfortunately, we don't have a Node.js server. So, I've set about finding ways to make this work with vanilla JS/jQuery. One iteration used Knockout.js. However, I found that API to be difficult to work with.

Now, I found this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/graphitekom/ap9gxo4L/), which uses Mistic's work in a standalone version. I'd prefer to use this, but one thing I can't quite piece together is how to create multiple Query Builders dynamically. (Rules will appear in a table as shown in the second link, and I'll need an Add Row button).

```
$('#builder').queryBuilder({

sortable: true,

filters: [{
    id: 'core_ID',
```

I've tried using the jQuery `.each()` function to create query builders bound to each element with a class of builder, but to no avail.

```
$.each('.builder').queryBuilder({
```

Can you guys show me how you'd go about dynamically creating new QueryBuilder objects as shown in the third link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `.builder` as a selector, which means you select **all** elements that have a `class="builder"` attribute.

If that is so, then you should be able to just call `$('.builder').queryBuilder(...` and it should use all elements that have the class `builder`

EDIT: It does in fact do so. But the cakephp query builder doesn't allow it (for whatever reason). So you **have** to use `each` in the way that i describe.

if you want to use the `each` function, you would to it like that:

```
$( ".builder" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).queryBuilder(...);
});
```

Explanation:

`$(".builder")` selects all elements that have a `class="builder"` attribute.
`.each` iterates over those elements. inside the function that is passed to `each` `this` contains the native DomElement (which is not a jquery element). Therefore `$(this)` gets the jQuery element for the DomElement  and .queryBuilder is called on it.

you can call .queryBuilder on pretty much any jQuery element unless it is an array of elements (it will throw an error).

so basically any selector + each in the way I use it should work.

here is a working fiddle with your example using 4 querybuilders: http://jsfiddle.net/ap9gxo4L/42/

Comment: I understand what you said about $(this) being the scoping mechanism for the jQuery element and the DOM Element, but how would you go about accessing a QueryBuilder object specifically? 

Problem is that the JSON generated when clicking the run button doesn't seem to be consistent with the expected value. I'd be happy with it running on one element or all four, but it just seems to be accessing a higher level hierarchy in the JSON it returns.

Comment: Okay, I think I got past that issue, I'll just target specific builders by their ID. But how would I go about getting an additional builder to render? I've got this jsfiddle set up: http://jsfiddle.net/ap9gxo4L/45/